# How can I click a dropdown-item button in html code, then get the text of the button in javascript on click event?

Tags: javascript, php

## My HTML Code

```
<li class="nav-item px-2 py-2 dropdown" id="applicant_list">

                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Applicant List
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <?php
                            $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=db_project; host = localhost", "root", "");
                            $find_mName = "SELECT mName 
                                            FROM `member` 
                                            INNER JOIN apply_chatroom 
                                            ON member.mId = apply_chatroom.mId
                                            WHERE cId =  '".$_GET['cId']."'";
                            $mName = $db->query($find_mName);
                            foreach ($mName as $mNames)
                            {?>
                          
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="apply_list" role="button"><?php echo $mNames['mName']; ?></a></li>
                      <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

## My JS Code

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#apply_list').click(function(){ 
        // I want to access the text inside anchor tag here, and assign it to a php variable
    });
});
</script>
```

What I want to do is when clicking the button, I can get the text inside the anchor tag($mNames['mName']) in my JS code. Then assign it to a php variable, because I will also use php code to do some SQL query inside the JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to create a PHP array with your PDO query, loop through it to use the array values for list items in your HTML code and for javascript click events.

In the example beneath the array elements of $mName are written in the id and value tag of the list elements. The id tag must be unique to be called from javascript. That's why I added the counter of the loop there which is removed in the javascript function afterwards.

In your code snippet the where clause of your PDO query is just as unclear as the expression $mNames['mName']. That's why I left them out. If you should use the where clause use prepared statemants in your PDO query due to security reasons:

PHP code:

```
<?php
...
// PDP query to create an array $mName
$find_mName = "SELECT mName 
                      FROM `member` 
                      INNER JOIN apply_chatroom 
                      ON member.mId = apply_chatroom.mId";
$stmt = $db->prepare($find_mName);
$stmt->execute();
$mName = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$stmt = null;

// loop through to get all array values of $mName
for($x=0;$x<count( $mName);$x++)
{
// write array element in string 
$nm = $mName[$x];
// write array values in id and value tag of li elements
?>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" id="<?php echo $nm."-".$x; ?>" onClick="getPHPValue(this.id)" role="button"><?php echo $nm; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
...
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
function getPHPValue(id)
{
const myArray = id.split("-");
let phpPart = myArray[0];
alert(phpPart);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, just another question. If I want to insert database when Clicking the button, I must use AJAX right? I guess the php code will only be excecuted when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Yes. You can pass the variable with ajax and call the result with get in your php code.